# can I use forEach loop along with the conditional statement if to only print out only even elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm at the very very very beginning of JS learning curve.
I am trying to use a loop on an array (containing six types of food) and then only print out the even elements:

```js
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];

foodArray.forEach(food => {
  if (foodArray.length % 2 = 0) {
  console.log(`${food}`); 
  }
});
```

Is this totally wrong? Should I use either for or while loop in association with the if conditional statement?

Comment: You can do what you have in mind but the code is not correct: first of all you have to check whether the index is odd or even (not the array length) then, as arrays starts from index 0, if you want the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc. element, you have to print the elements that have an odd index

Comment: Ach you're so right @secan! would this be considered okay then?
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];
for (i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i += 2) {
  console.log(foodArray[i+1]);
}

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly valid, although you could start the loop from 1 (`for (let i = 1; i < foodArray.length; i += 2) { console.log(foodArray[i]) }`) so that you avoid the first unnecessary loop and you can use directly `foodArray[i]` instead of `foodArray[i+1]`

Comment: beautiful. true! thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal `for`-Loop would be the way to go in my opinion. The `forEach`-loop is better if you don't need to reference the index of the elements. In your case you need the index, because it tells you whether an element is even or not. Here is a little example:

```
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];
for (i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(foodArray[i]);
  }
}
```

A `forEach` loop of course can also take the index using another parameter in the lambda expression, like in sabbit.alam's answer, but imo a normal `for`-Loop is better for learning in the beginning.

An even better `for`-Loop would be the following, where the `if`-expression is nested in the `for`-Loop itself by incrementing in 2-steps:

```
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];
for (i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i += 2) {
  console.log(foodArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake instead of equality checking you have been using = as assignment operator here `(foodArray.length % 2 = 0)`
Even if you fix that issue by using `===` instead of `=` it will print all the values if the length of food array is even otherwise it will print nothing.

You should do the following,

```js
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];

foodArray.forEach((food, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
  console.log(`${food}`); 
  }
});
```

That will print all the even indexed value.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to avoid forEach loop because it will increase the call stack size(On every loop new function is called) having said that Here is the correction on your code.

```
foodArray.forEach((food, index)=> { if (index % 2 === 0) { console.log(food); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways :

```js
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"]

foodArray.forEach((food, index) =>
  {
  if (!(index %2))  console.log(`s1 -> ${food}`)
  })
  
console.log('-----------')
// or 
for ( let i=0; i<foodArray.length; i+=2 )
   console.log(`s2 -> ${foodArray[i]}`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this wtihout doing the index modulus check - simply increment the index by 2 on each iteration instead of 1. This is more efficient because it prevents the check on each iteration (not important on this list - but imagine if you had an array of 1 million items.

```js
const foodArray = ["pizza", "tacos", "fruit", "veggies", "hummus", "tea"];

for (i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i+=2) {
  console.log(foodArray[i]); // gives pizza fruit hummus
}
```